# Uncertainties / errors for non-continuous minimizer in Octave

Tags: octave, minimization, uncertainty

I am currently using fminsearch to minimize a non-continuous function, with x = vector of 7 variables.
It works well but has two problems (for me): 1) it is slow, 2) more importantly it doesn't return any uncertainties / errors for the variables in x.
Is there a minimiser function that would do the trick and return uncertainties / errors for x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself.

```
[x, fval] = fminsearch (fun, x0, options);
[hess,err] = hessian(fun,x);
uncert = sqrt(diag(inv(hess)));
```

The hessian suite is available from:
[Adaptive Robust Numerical Differentiation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13490-adaptive-robust-numerical-differentiation)
Thanks to  John D'Errico the author of the suite.
This is time expensive (it is slow) but works very well.